# Remove all chars in a text file that should contain just numbers

Tags: java, bufferedreader, string-comparison

I found a java program that compares two text files in java with eachother and made it so that it lists all lines/entries which are not in both text files.

```
package Exercise1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String first = "migratielijst.txt";
    String second = "complete.txt";
    BufferedReader fBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(first));
    BufferedReader sBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(second));

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((first = fBr.readLine()) != null) {
        strings.add(first);
        first.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
    }
    fBr.close();

    while ((second = sBr.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!(strings.contains(second))) {
            System.out.println(second);
        } 
    }
    sBr.close();
}
}
```

The line I found to remove all characters (below) does not do what I want it to do.

```
first.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
```

say the text file looks like this:

```
8271910
8271911
//8271912
8271913
8271914
8271915
```

And the text file it is comparing to looks like this:

```
8271910
8271911
8271912
8271913
8271914
8271915
```

it would list 8271912 because it is commented out in the first text file.
now if I modify the first text file and put a name before it I want my program to remove the characters (not take them into account when comparing).
Example:

```
Anya 8271910
8271911
//8271912
8271913
8271914
8271915
```

The problem is my program returns this:

```
8271910
8271912
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand your comparison logic, or why it would necessarily even work.  Are these IDs sorted in some way?  If not, then how can you report entries not in both files without first reading in both files?

Comment: In Java, String is immutable. Review the first loop logic.

Comment: Also, do not reuse variables like you did with 'first'. Use meaningful names like migrateFilename.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem comes from this lines :

```
strings.add(first);
first.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
```

In Java, Strings are immutable. So, what you're doing is adding the brut string to your list, then creating a new string with the wanted modifications. But the new string is ignored in your program.

Here is a quick fix:

```
strings.add(first.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem statement seems to say that you want to find terms which appear in one file, or the other, but *not* in both.  In terms of data structures, a set, not a list, would make the most sense, because we can use set differences to get the result you want.  In the code below, I read both file into separate sets, then form a third set consisting of the differences of each set on the other.

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> s1Copy = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>();

String term;
while ((term = fBr.readLine()) != null) {
    s1.add(term);
    s1Copy.add(term);
}
fBr.close();

while ((term = sBr.readLine()) != null) {
    s2.add(term);
}
sBr.close();

Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();
unique.add(s1.removeAll(s2));
unique.add(s2.removeAll(s1Copy));

System.out.println("Unique terms:");
for (String s : unique) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: s1.removeAll(s2) -> returns a boolean value. U cannot add(it should be addAll, not add). When u do s1.removeAll(s2) then it's pointless to do s2.removeAll(s1) since now its known that s1 will not contain any member of s2. Cheers.

Comment: This is really ugly and sorry about I'm saying it :) I would prefer something like:
unique.addAll(s1);
        unique.addAll(s2);
        unique.removeIf(x -> s1.contains(x) && s2.contains(x));

Comment: Too much pain brother.  My main goal was just to point out that the business requirement could use set logic instead of list comparisons.

Comment: Just to clarify Set.retainAll(Collection c) -> removes all elements but the ones contained in both the collections (Intersection).

Answer (score 0):

You can just try something like this

```
anyString = anyString.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```